# jquery date picker inside the angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to show current date in the texbox. i am using jquery datepicker with angular directive. but current date did not display.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cDate" xx/>
app.directive('xx', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

        element.datepicker({
            dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',
            setDate:'0',
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                });

            }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in controller

```
  var date = new Date();
  $scope.cDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
```

Rewrite your directive as

```
app.directive("xx", function() {

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    // CALL THE "datepicker()" METHOD USING THE "element" OBJECT.
    element.datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
  }

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: link
  };
});
```

```js
// Module declaration
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
// Controller declaration
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var date = new Date();
  $scope.cDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
}]);

myApp.directive("xx", function() {

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    // CALL THE "datepicker()" METHOD USING THE "element" OBJECT.
    element.datepicker();
    element.datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      setDate: new Date()
    });
  }

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: link
  };
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="cDate" xx/>
</div>
```

Comment: when page load , i need to show current date (today) in the textbox. i am trying to do it using jquery setDate method. but it is not working .

Comment: setDate: new Date() in your code not working to me.. can u help me

Comment: Dear Geethu, i found another solution its working to me. i called ng-init function in the textbox. ng-init="setCurrentDate()".

Comment: Please check the answer

Comment: Try adding this in controller

var date = new Date();
$scope.cDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

Comment: my solution its working. anyway thanks for the effort

Comment: As Angular docs say you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope, and that a controller should contain only the business logic needed for a single view

Comment: @user1177842, you don't need ngInit, just initialize the value directly in your controller.

The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.